# Css cover image resize when mouse is over a dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my website, i have created a css menu that is a dropdown menu on some elements. I use an image as a full cover. When i put my mouse over an element of the dropdown menu, the cover changes position. My test site is http://unibenefits.gr/test2/tripoli .

Comment: Can you explain a little better what is going wrong? When i hover over the dropdowns things seem to look right? What do you mean by "cover"?

Comment: Hello Eirinn it seems like this does not appear in all browsers... i have tested it in Chrome and the cover breaks. When i test it on Mozilla or even IE all works like a charm...

Comment: Try, instead of using cover, to set the height and width to 100%. Cover is a CSS3 property (as far as i know) and may not be fully supported by all browsers.

Comment: Also just a little good advice, always run a "reset CSS" (google it). It removes standard padding, margin and so on from elements. Many browsers set properties as they see fit and that can severely impact styling in the long run :)

Answer (score 0):

When you set a `background-image` to `cover`, it will fill the entirety of the element (usually `HTML` or `Body`) that you assign it to. This will change if the size of the element changes - e.g. if you resize your browser window, the `background-image` will resize to fit it.

Something in your dropdown menu is causing your site design to overflow horizontally (i.e. the design changes slightly on certain rollovers, so the design goes very slightly wider than the browser window). This, in turn, creates a horizontal scrollbar. The horizontal scrollbar takes up room in your browser window, effectivley resizing it. This is why your `cover` background-image is resizing - it's not actually changing position, though they look similar.

If you can identify what in your menu is causing the horizontal scrollbar to appear, you'll fix the problem.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer. It seems like this does not appear in all browsers... i have tested it in Chrome and the cover breaks. When i test it on Mozilla or even IE all works like a charm.. Cant find what exaclty is wrong with my divs... I am kind of new in Css and html....

Comment: Hi @user3193190 - every browser will render the page slightly differently. There's probably not something wrong with your code per se, it's just trial and error to get them to look as close as possible to each other. If you get it to look right in webkit browsers such as Chrome and Safari, it'll probably look okay in Firefox too, though things may go off kilter in IE. However, to take care of that, you can use conditional statements to add a few bits of extra "correction" css for IE only. http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/